# How to reset grid paging content on resolution change?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have used a grid template from BootStrap and the paging for that grid is showing as per the attached image 1. Now when i change the screen resolution of the browser the paging content gets break into two lines as per attached image 2 instead of in a single line.

But once i refresh the page it loads the paging correctly as the image 3. But i want that content right after changing of resolution.

Below is the code of JS by using React for that paging class
var ul = React.DOM.ul({className: 'pagination pagination-sm', role: 'menubar', 'aria-label': globalizationFactory.translate('STORMS_PAGER'), key: 'pager_container'}, [firstLi, prevLi, this.getPages(currentPageIndex + 1, totalPages), nextLi, lastLi]);

```
        var mainClass = this.props.className ? 'container-fluid ' + this.props.className : 'container-fluid';
        return React.DOM.div({className: mainClass,key: 'pager_wrapper'},
          React.DOM.div({className: 'row',key: 'pager_wrapper_inner'},
            React.DOM.div({className: 'col-sm-12', style: {textAlign: 'center'},key: 'pager_innerWrapper'}, ul)));
```

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Image 1:
[image]
Image 2:

[image]

Image 3:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is listen for window resize events and have that trigger a render. In React, if you change state, your component will render. You can do something like this inside of your component that is doing the rendering.

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    windowWidth: window.innerWidth,
    windowHeight: window.innerHeight
  };
},
componentDidMount: function() {
  return window.addEventListener('resize', this._handleResize);
},
componentWillUnmount: function() {
  return window.removeEventListener('resize', this._handleResize);
},
_handleResize: function() {
  if (this.state.windowWidth !== window.innerWidth || this.state.windowHeight !== window.innerHeight) {
    return this.setState({
      windowWidth: window.innerWidth,
      windowHeight: window.innerHeight
    });
  }
}
```